# How to read a sensor in c but then use that input in python

Tags: python, c, popen

I have a flow sensor that I have to read with c because python isn't fast enough but the rest of my code is python. What I want to do is have the c code running in the background and just have the python request a value from it every now and then. I know that popen is probably the easiest way to do this but I don't fully understand how to use it. I don't want completed code I just want a way to send text/numbers back and forth between a python and a c code. I am running raspbian on a raspberry pi zero w. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Python is not fast enough to read a sensor but fast enough for everything else? Sounds suspicious.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The flow sensor just sends a signal every time it goes round and because python is interpreted not compiled it misses some so thinks the flow is slower than it is.

Comment: Write two different programs and use IPC? What kind of system are you using anyhow?

Comment: How often does the sensor produce a value, as there are very few sensors that produce THAT much data that python cannot handle it?

Comment: @Lundin I don't fully understand what you are asking and what is IPC because I was planning to write 2 programs

Comment: Are you saying you have some asynchronous signal that is going on and off and you have to catch it when it is on? The only reliable way to read it would be to use interrupts and/or DMA/FIFO.

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes but python would be too slow with its interrupts

Comment: Try typing "IPC" in Google and read the first link.

Comment: @Lundin I was planning on using some form of IPC then but was looking for the syntax for some specific one because I couldn't find enough information online.

Comment: Nobody can tell you what you should use because you haven't mentioned which system this is for. Still.

Comment: What do you mean which system it is for

Comment: Sounds like [xy problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: @klutt apart from the fact that I want to solve problem y not problem x

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html

Comment: @Ôrel but would it not still be running at python speed because it is running from within python and that would add complexity from needing to split it into a thread

Comment: You seem to assume that this is not possible to do with Python. I find it hard to believe. Furthermore, you should present your attempt to solve the problem. I see no code at all here.

Comment: @klutt That is because I am trying to find a way to do it so I can't include code because I am not sure of a method. Also, it may be possible in python but python is too slow

Comment: You say that you were thinking of using Popen. Well, study the documentation and try it out. At the moment this question is way to broad, so I'm going to vote to close it.

Comment: I really don't understand if Python is not fast enough and you need C. Invoke C from Python solves the issue. Looks like you are not doing it well in Python more than a C vs Python issue.

Comment: As long as you can't tell us wich system you are using (raspberry?), what kind of sensor it is and how it is connected noone can say anything. For reading the sensor you propably need interrupts. Otherwise you are propably busy-looping (wich is always a bad idea).

Answer (score 0):

Probably not a full answer, but I expect it gives some hints and it is far too long for a comment. You should think twice about your requirements, because it will probably not be that easy depending on your proficiency in C and what OS you are using.

If I have correctly understood, you have a sensor that sends data (which is already weird unless the sensor is an intelligent one). You want to write a C program that will read that data and either buffer it, and retain only last (you did not say...) and at the same time will wait for requests from a Python script to give it back what it has received (and kept) from the sensor. That probably means a dual thread program with quite a bit of synchronization.

You will also need to specify the communication way between C and Python. You can certainly use the subprocess module, but do not forget to use unbuffered output in C. But you could also imagine an independant program that uses a FIFO or a named piped with a well defined protocol for external requests, in order to completely separate both problems.

So my opinion is that this is currently too broad for a single SO question...

Comment: Thanks for answering. A bit of clarification - the sensor sends pulses and the c code needs to count how many since python's last request.

Comment: If it is just count pulse, it sounds weird that you cannot do it in Python.

Comment: Ok, all depends now if you are programming on an embedded system with direct low level IO access, or on a PC or equivalent where you could read from a serial port. My advice: start with a C code that receives data from the sensor. Then add it the ability to process requests from a different channel. An only then wonder how to interface it from Python